# How to check that user is "db_owner" (like in SQLServer) but in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to Postgres and would like to understand how to check if a user is db_owner. I'd like to know the same for SQL Server, as well.

How can I check that user is owner of the database(db_owner)?

Maybe another option is to check that user can do create, alter, drop with tables in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ownership of a database is stored in `pg_database`, you can do:

```
select datname, 
       datdba::regrole::text, 
       datdba::regrole::text = current_user as is_owner
from pg_database;
```

This will show you for each database if the current user is the owner.

Or if you want to test if a specific user is the owner of a specific database. You can add a WHERE clause to limit that to a specific database or use a fixed user name in the boolean expression of the SELECT list.

Starting with Postgres 14, there is a [predefined role](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/predefined-roles.html)  `pg_database_owner` which can also be used to test this:

```
select pg_has_role(current_database, 'pg_database_owner', 'member');
```

This will only work for the current database, you can't test ownership for other databases with that function.

However, a user doesn't need to be the owner of the database in order to be able to create tables (or other objects) in a schema.

If you want to find out if a user can create objects, you can use the `has_schema_privilege()` function:

```
select has_schema_privilege(current_user, 'public', 'create');
```

Answer (score 1):

The query can be shorter but I wish to do it step-by-step

```
with db_owner as (
select u.usename, d.datname
from pg_database d, pg_user u
where d.datdba=u.usesysid
and d.datname=current_database()
)
select 
case when db_owner.usename = session_user then
'user is db_owner'
else
'user is not db_owner'
end is_owner
from db_owner;
```